# Public functions in VBA that use "vbCr" incorrectly return text with quotes when pasted outside of Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a string of text using VBA. When pasting the resulting string however, it's always surrounded by quotes. This only occurs when using an enter key.

I've tried to use `vbLf`, `vbCrLf` & `vbCr`, all with the same results.

```
Public Function tester()
    tester = "first line" & vbCr & "next line"
End Function
```

When using the formula `=tester()` in a workbook, the result is as expected within Excel. However, the result we'd expect when pasting - in Notepad, say - the is the following:

> first line
>
> next line

However, the actual result is:

> "first line
>
> next line"

These quotes are undesirable and I will be very grateful to hear what you have to say. Thank you!

Comment: Having tried this myself just now, I dont experience your issue. Could you confirm what version of Excel you are using, also if you `debug.print tester` what is the returned string? Also, if I use this as an Excel formula `=tester()` it doesnt have the line break, is this also the case for you?

Comment: @Mr.Burns In Office 365 you won't "see" the `CR` but it is there. (You need to examine character by character to find it). And the problem with quotes on pasting to notepad is also present.

Answer (score 1):

Using Word as an intermediate may help.

https://superuser.com/questions/324271/how-to-copy-multi-line-text-from-excel-without-quotes

[Leave out quotes when copying from cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910288/leave-out-quotes-when-copying-from-cell)

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/copying-multiline-text/m-p/44683

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/7177/how-to-copy-multi-line-text-hard-return-from-excel-without-extra-quotes

(first 4 results of a google search for "excel copy multiline cell paste quotes")