# Outputting text including " in XlsxWriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have XML data I am trying to write to an Excel cell using XlsxWriter.  This XML data has attribute.value pairs, and the values are enclosed in double-quotes (e.g. name="Bob").  This writes *almost* successfully: the quotes are doubled (e.g. name=""Bob"").  The entire XML block is also enclosed in ".

I have tried formatting the cell as text:

`text_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '@'})

but that does not appear to have any effect.  I started with this cell as part of a row, with write_row(), am now writing the individual cell with or without formatting, `and as a formula, all with the same results.  How do I get it to stop inserting " into my data?

Comment: Please create a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I may have found the culprit: Excel itself. When I double-click in the cell to bring up the Edit window, the data shows properly without doubled quotes. Copying this data and pasting it into a plain text document again shows properly, without doubled quotes. On the other hand, if I simply single-click on a cell and copy, that data gets pasted with the additional quotes (quotes also wrap the entire XML block). So I need to figure out if there is an easier way to copy the correct data in Excel, so that I can select multiple cells at a time

More tests show that this is with multi-line text.

Comment: As I see from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910288/leave-out-quotes-when-copying-from-cell?rq=2 this a well-known problem without the solution that I need.  I will see if I can redesign to avoid the need for this.

Comment: As I see from stackoverflow.com/questions/24910288/… this a well-known problem without the solution that I need. I will see if I can redesign to avoid the need for this.