Removing quotes added when pasting from Excel to Outlook
I'm a salesperson trying to reduce busywork in how I reach out to people via email, by using Excel. I was using Outlook templates, but then I had to manually type in all the blanks which gets to be time-consuming. Now I'm trying to work with an exported list of people in Excel, and copy-pasting the results of my formula into each email (after which I tweak as necessary). The problem I'm seeing is quote marks inserted before and after the text I paste.
Example Excel formula:
=CONCAT("Biospecimens for ",Table1[@[First Name]],"'s ",PROPER(Table1[@[Focus Area]])," Research
Hi ",Table1[@[First Name]],",
Your work in ",Table1[@[Focus Area]]," at ",
Table1[@[Company Name]]," caught my eye as someone that supports scientists in this space. I thought you'd find value in (redacted company name)'s high-quality biospecimens,
"," such as blood, tissue, and cells. Our diverse sample types and indications can be customized to fit your specific requirements.",
"Could we set up a meeting for next week? I’m free on Monday or Tuesday at 10am CST.

I look forward to connecting with you. Have a fantastic day!")

Result in Outlook when I paste with the "keep text only" option:

"Biospecimens for Jill's Immuno-Oncology Research
Hi Jill,
Your work in immuno-oncology at ABC company caught my eye as someone
that supports scientists in this space. I thought you'd find value in
(redacted company name)'s high-quality biospecimens, such as blood,
tissue, and cells. Our diverse sample types and indications can be
customized to fit your specific requirements.
Could we set up a meeting for next week? I’m free on Monday or Tuesday
at 10am CST.
I look forward to connecting with you. Have a fantastic day!"

I don't want those quotes to be pasted at the beginning and end, since I'd have to remove them manually every time.
Here is a link to my example file, with most data removed for privacy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13hbGdu9VoGwiPTyDT23JuBi1qvh5OSAs/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100375049889635789383&rtpof=true&sd=true
I am using Excel 365 and Outlook 365.
I'm hoping for an easy formulaic way to solve this, similar to putting a TRIM() function around the entire CONCAT function. Or perhaps a helper column?
I couldn't find a way to make a find-replace work in this case.
I tried the CLEAN() function, but it removes the carriage returns which is even worse than seeing the quote marks.
P.S. I opened the file in Google Drive and the formula doesn't work, looks like because CONCAT() can only take two arguments in the Sheets version.

I can't comment on your quote problem, but it sounds like you really want a mail merge, driven by your Excel document.

This answer may help with your quoting issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24913557/622391

@SimonMᶜKenzie Thank you very much for your help! Yes, I'm trying to do a mail merge, that's correct. I've heard negative feedback about several free mail-merge programs, so...DIY. The article you linked did indeed solve my problem. (user3616725's version). It wasn't quite the type of solution I was envisioning, but functionality is the most important. Problem fixed! :)

Glad to hear you got it working! By the way, mail merge is built into Office, so you may want to try that out. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3
